# Score not adding properly ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I have this score counter for my project but instead of adding +1 or subtracting -1, it'll subtract 2 and add 7. This is the code I'm using.

I have it so one page has two buttons (startBTN and endBTN) and when you click on startBTN, it will load another swf on top of this swf and add one point. However, when it does this, it adds 7 points. The other button is meant to subtract one point and pull up that respective swf and instead subtracts 2.

I have tried this on a separate page and it will subtract 4 instead of 2 even if they aren't linked together.

```
var saveDataObject:SharedObject;
var currentScore:int;

init(); // this line goes directly beneath the variables

function init():void{ // call once to set everything up

saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("test"); // give the save data a location
 currentScore = 0; //start with 0 score

startBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addScore); // clicking on +1
 endBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, subtractScore); // clicking on Save

function addScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
 currentScore += 1; // add 1 to the score
 updateScoreText(); // update the textfield
}
function subtractScore(e:MouseEvent):void{
 currentScore -= 1; // add 1 to the score
 updateScoreText(); // update the textfield
}

function saveData(e:MouseEvent):void{
 saveDataObject.data.savedScore = currentScore; // set the saved score to the current score
 trace("Data Saved!");
 saveDataObject.flush(); // immediately save to the local drive
 trace(saveDataObject.size); // this will show the size of the save file, in bytes
}

function loadData():void{
 currentScore = saveDataObject.data.savedScore; // set the current 
score to the saved score
 trace("Data Loaded!");
 //return currentScore;
}

function updateScoreText():void
{
 txtScore.text = "Score: " + String(currentScore); // set the text property of the txtScore
 trace(currentScore);
}


 if(saveDataObject.data.savedScore == null){ // checks if there is save data
      trace("No saved data yet."); // if there isn't any data on the computer...
      saveDataObject.data.savedScore = currentScore; // ...set the savedScore to 0
 } else {
      trace("Save data found."); // if we did find data...
      loadData(); // ...load the data
 }

 //updateScoreText(); // finally, update the text field
}
```

Comment: Don't know if this is now solved but **don't put functions inside other functions**...

Comment: This code should work, what swf you try to load?